# how to store and retrieve user comments in html pages without server side languages

Tags: html, web

i'm creating an educational website in which there are lots of individual html pages. How can i read user's comments and then display their comments in my page?
my point is how to store their comments in html pages because i think they can't actually access data bases.
for example please
[take a look at this web page](http://wpftutorial.net/XAML.html)

Comment: One way or another, the comments have to be stored on a server by some server side language.  This means either stored on your server, or someone else's (like disqus suggested below)

Comment: Just because the extension is .html doesn't mean that there isn't a server behind it rendering it dynamically. The comments are being stored in a database on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) is probably your best bet if you don't want to build a commenting interface yourself -- it's really easy to implement. Facebook's commenting plugin also does the same sort of thing but requires a FB account, whereas Disqus is more open to other platforms.

Comment: i also like using Disqus , it is really effective and easy-to-use.

Comment: Where my information, i mean comments are saved in this tool ?

Comment: @AliRashidi Comments are saved on Disqus' servers.